# Application design: how to have GUI respond to changes in data

Tags: c#, oop, architecture

This is more of a design pattern question, so there will be no code and lots of words, please bear with me. I am writing a business application (in C#, using WinForms). There is a POCO-style object representing the set of data that user is currently working on - a "document" with all pertinent data.

Business operations are implemented in application layer in a set of managers each responsible for its own aspect of the application.
One of the aspects is recalculation of certain summaries which are being persisted in object's data. The managers know which operations over the data may require recalculations and invoke them in appropriate times.

GUI (WinForms) part is responsible for translating user's interactions into calls to the application layer. Let's say, you click on Add button, the click event locates the ObjectListManager class and calls manager.AddObject(...). Since ObjectListManager knows that this would require an update to the summary, it makes sure it is recalculated (by calling some other managers internally).

What I would like to know is this. I need my GUI to refresh the summaries on the form. My first impulse is to set up a delegate placeholder (where?!), register a GUI-level method as a delegate for that callback and have this method called by the application layer. But I am not sure this does not contradict the abstraction of the business operations that I want to maintain keeping them agnostic of the GUI layer. 
On the other hand, an alternative is to build this into the response to user interactions on the GUI level, i.e. the click on Add button should know that after a call to manager.AddObject(), it should query recalculated data and present it in the GUI.

I lack some experience/knowledge and cannot figure out how to design this properly. 
The long version of the answer is probably to finish reading the "gang of four" book, but if somebody can come up with good practical advice now, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: There's already a pattern for this: Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM). If you can use WPF, its *already* set up to use it.

Comment: To expand on what BradleyDotNET said: WPF contains a so-called 'data binding' system. GUI elements can be given an object to observe. They'll read specific properties from that object and they'll refresh themselves when that object raises certain events (property-changed, collection-changed). Your GUI obviously needs to know something about what it's displaying, but not the other way around - the underlying objects don't need to know who or what is reacting to their events. You could swap or remove the GUI and the rest of your code would still work.

Comment: Pieter, absolutely, yes - GUI should know the objects it's playing with, but business objects should be possible to reuse with another presentation layer - that's the goal. Unfortunately, switching to WPF isn't an option at this time. Besides, I would suspect "observing objects" would come with an overhead. In my case the points of contact are quite few.. so I'm sitting here wondering how to build something in this spirit, but with plain old winforms at the frontend and at a low cost.

Answer (score 1):

After reading M.Fowler's article here: http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/SeparatedPresentation.html

and also a couple of texts on implementing the Observer pattern here
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/769084/Observer-Pattern-Csharp
and here
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/88278/Observer-in-NET-with-IObserver-T

I ended up implementing a simplistic observer pattern with my data model as the subject (implemented in a base class) and the form as observer.

To my personal taste it sort of makes the data object a bit more than a POCO than I wanted it to be, but hey, if it's good enough for Martin Fowler...